# Get the beginning of the day in timestamp using Momentjs library

Tags: javascript, momentjs

For instance the timestamp is: 1542769200 which its output is: GMT: Wednesday, 21 November 2018 03:00:00.
However what I am trying to achieve is to get the beginning of this day, by having the hour, minutes and seconds set to 00.00.00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
moment(moment(moment().unix() * 1000).startOf('day').unix() * 1000)
```

Comment: I have val = 1542769200;
How and where do I use this variable in the expression that you have provided?

Comment: Remember that timestamp is in seconds, but in javascript we operate in miliseconds, so you should multiply your timestamp by 1000. When you have your moment date then you check the start of the day, and you can convert it to timestamp by the '.unix()' method..

Comment: This does not really give me what I am trying to achieve.
Take this is mind as timestamp: 1542769200, according to your expression this does not return me the beginning of its day

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```js
var timestamp = 1542769200;
var date = moment.unix(timestamp).startOf('day')

console.log('date:', moment.unix(timestamp).format())
console.log('start of day:', date.format())
console.log('new unix:', date.unix())
console.log('test:', moment.unix(date.unix()).format())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you looking for :

```js
moment().startOf('day').unix()
```